# Determine number of possible paths in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph consisting of a start point $S$, a finish point $F$ and a number of intermediate points $P_i$. The points are connected by a set of edges, as shown in the graph below.  I need to determine the number of unique paths connecting the start to the finish. The rules:

- The number of points per path is not fixed
- Each path can pass by a point one time only (to avoid loops)

I'm a graph theory noob and I'm sure this is a quite common problem.  Do you have suggestions to where should I look to get an introduction to the problem, and suggestions on how to solve it?  Ideally, I'm looking for an equation or numerical procedure.

[image: graph]

Comment: There should be standard treatments available on the web. What searches did you do?  A typical approach is breadth first traversal of the tree of paths.  Gerhard "Is This For A Class?" Paseman, 2019.11.12.

Comment: Discussion for directed graphs: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-two-vertices/

Comment: Looks like in general it's a hard question. https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/DirkKroese/ps/robkro_rev.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that in general this is a hard problem, this seems to be a case where off-the-shelf software can be of use.

In Mathematica:

```
g = Graph[
  {s <-> p1, s <-> p2, p1 <-> p3, p1 <-> p4, s <-> p3, p2 <-> p3, 
   p2 <-> p5, p2 <-> p6, p3 <-> p4, p4 <-> p5, p3 <-> p6, p4 <-> p7, 
   p5 <-> p6,p3 <-> p5, p5 <-> p7, p6 <-> p7,p7 <-> F, p5 <-> F, p6 <-> F},
  VertexLabels -> Automatic,
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
numpaths = Length[FindPath[g, s, F, Infinity, All]]
```

$235$.

Here are just 12 of the paths:

[image]

As for sources of information on this problem, I'd recommend (for a newbie) ***A first course in Graph Theory*** by Chartrand and Zhang (Dover).

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: another possible approach is to use the function `shortest_simple_paths` from [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/). As a reference, see [here](https://medium.com/apprentice-journal/the-graph-theory-an-introduction-in-python-5906d5be0e4b).